# History of religiosity decline after haskalah

Tags: history, hashkafah-philosophy, theology, statistics, secular-culture

Is any reason given by religiously Jewish theologians and thinkers for why religiosity and observance amongst Jews declined after the Haskalah?

Are there any opinions rabbinic authorities have given about orthodoxy rebounding in the future.

And are there any views about  what minimum statistic of Jews  will remain committed to Torah during decline of spirituality? Like do any rabbanim see it as some sort of divine punishment?

Comment: I think we should ask about the level of observance during the Golah until the Haskalah. Current levels are typical for long stretches of Jewish History -- the majority were worshipping Avodah Zarah throughout Bayis Rishon, the crowd that returned to Israel in Zerubavel's and Ezra's day were mostly intermarried, Anshei Keneses haGdolah brought us in, but before Chanukah we had the Misyavnim, and after, the Tzeduqim and other sects... So maybe ask whether struggling against a non-observant majority is messianic -- a return to the where we were when there were Nevi'im and Batei Miqdash.

Comment: After all, returning people to the tradition is an explicit part of the messianic promise. הִנֵּ֤ה אָנֹכִי֙ שֹׁלֵ֣חַ לָכֶ֔ם אֵ֖ת אֵלִיָּ֣ה הַנָּבִ֑יא לִפְנֵ֗י בּ֚וֹא י֣וֹם הֹ' הַגָּד֖וֹל וְהַנּוֹרָֽא׃ כדוְהֵשִׁ֤יב לֵב־אָבוֹת֙ עַל־בָּנִ֔ים וְלֵ֥ב בָּנִ֖ים עַל־אֲבוֹתָ֑ם פֶּן־אָב֕וֹא וְהִכֵּיתִ֥י אֶת־הָאָ֖רֶץ חֵֽרֶם׃ And the Rambam says such a restoration is one of the jobs of the mashiach  וְחוֹזְרִין כָּל הַמִּשְׁפָּטִים בְּיָמָיו כְּשֶׁהָיוּ מִקֹּדֶם. (H' Melakhim 11:1)

Comment: What do you mean by "after the Haskalah"?

Comment: Isn't the answer obvious? People were influenced by the Haskalah and therefore became less observant.

Comment: @N.T. why "therefore"

Comment: @DoubleAA The point of the Enlightenment/haskala was to dethrone religion and replace it with "reason". A good book about the topic is "The PIty of it All" by Amos Elon.

Comment: @N.T. that's nonsense. The enlightenment didn't have "a point". It wasn't a cabal of people who did something with a particular goal. That's historically backwards.

Comment: @DoubleAA They had a philosophy that they espoused. Major figures were Voltaire and the Encyclopedists of France. France to this day has secularism (laicite) as one of its main values. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secularism_in_France

Comment: @N.T. pointing to individual people or individual conclusions doesn't justify your claim above. No one has denied *that* people left religion, the question is why.

Comment: @MichaBerger Not necessarily were any of those a majority, and in fact there is evidence to the contrary. Avodah zarah - consider that all the ovdei habaal in the Kingdom of Yisrael fit into one building, and 80 soldiers were enough to kill all of them. Intermarriage - the end of Ezra lists 113 people out of tens of thousands. Misyavnim - also no evidence they were a majority. Tzedukim - Josephus states flatly that "the common people" were against them. Etc.

Comment: The polytheists during Bayis Rishon were such a majority, archeologists haven't been able to find the monotheists yet! And why do you think Seifer Yechezqeil or Hosheiah look the way they do? The majority of returnees were intermarried; 113 didn't let go of their old families at the Mussar Shmuess (Ezra 9). As for the מתיוונים, Al haNissim explicitly calls them the רבים!

Comment: @Meir ... Josephus's common people were not Perushim either. Chaveirim were a minority. The Tzeduqim had enough power to make the Sanhedrin meaningless for a while, as they sat on it. We had witnesses lying about when they saw a new moon. Kohanim aGadolim had to be suspected, although Kohanim tended to Sadducism more than other groups - if you had the Melukhah and the Kehunah, you had all the more reason to deprecate the third source of authority.

Comment: @MichaBerger How would they "find the monotheists"? An aniconic religion doesn't leave archeological traces. Sefer Yechezkel and Hoshea and so forth look the way they do because even one Jew sinning is too many (cf. Shemos 16:28 where everyone is blamed for the actions of the few מן העם, and Yehoshua 7:11 where חטא ישראל means that one man, Achan, sinned). The 113 - no, there would be no reason to argue המלאכה גדולה לא ליום אחד ולא לשנים if most had already done so by then. Misyavnim - *together with the Greek army* they were the רבים, not to mention that not all the frum Jews were fighting.

Comment: And, @MichaBerger, I never said the common people were Perushim. But they were *on their side* against the Tzedukim. That the latter had the powers you mention - sure, a rich and powerful minority has power all out of proportion to their numbers (look at current events for similar examples).

Comment: @Meir, I decided not to argue about the demographics of.various sects in the late Bayis Sheini era. If the Perushim were a minority, most Jews were not properly observing halakhah. Which was the belief I posted the first time that you questioned. They don't actually have to have been Tzeduqim to make my point, so I ecided argue whether they were or weren't.

Comment: At a time when 10% of the Roman Empire thought they were Jewish, it wasn't because halachic geirus was the normal route for "conversion".

Comment: @MichaBerger Being careless with some mitzvos doesn't equal "not properly observing halakhah," otherwise by that logic anyone who speaks lashon hara would be classified as non-religious too. Most of the amei haaretz separated maaser properly, and just weren't versed in the details of tum'ah v'taharah. They wouldn't even lie on Shabbos (Yerushalmi Demai 4:1)! || And what do you mean by "thought that they were Jewish"? What makes you think they weren't in fact born Jews or halachic geirim? See the figures in Pesachim 64b.

Comment: In the introduction to the sefer מנהג ישראל תורה , the author discusses this at length. Essentially, he makes the case that the differentiating factor between the Haskalah and other waves of indoctrination and oppression is that the Haskalah specifically attacked Jewish *customs*, which are what truly keep most Jews from leaving their faith, more so than halachah. 

He cites (from a Midrash) that the Jewish people merited to be redeemed from Egypt because they held on to their customs, even though they were serving idols and otherwise entirely like Egyptians.